# How can I use setValue declaratively?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

I would like to use `setValue` in the declaration of `occupation`. How do I declare?

**// ** Hooks**

```
  // for occupation wizard
  const {
    reset: occupationReset,
    control: occupationControl,
    handleSubmit: handleOccupationSubmit,
    
    formState: { errors: occupationErrors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultFields.occupation.fields.init,
    mode: 'onBlur',
    resolver: yupResolver(defaultFields.occupation.schema)
  })

  // for occupation financial
  const {
    reset: financialReset,
    control: financialControl,
    handleSubmit: handleFinancialSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors: financialErrors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultFields.financial.fields.init,
    mode: 'onBlur',
    resolver: yupResolver(defaultFields.financial.schema)
  })
```

**// ** Handle financial **

```
const handleClickLoadPIX = async value => {
    setValue('pf_pix_key', response.content.pixKey)
    setValue('pf_bank_name', response.content.bankName)
}
```

**// ** JSX financial**

```
<Controller
    name='pj_pix_key'
    control={financialControl}
    rules={{ required: false }}
    render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
      <OutlinedInput
        value={value}
        label='Chave PIX'
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        id='pj_pix_key'
        error={Boolean(financialErrors.pj_pix_key)}
        type='text'
        placeholder='ex.: 12345678'
        aria-describedby='pj_pix_key-helper'
        labelId='pj_pix_key-label'
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position='end'>
            <Tooltip title='Carregar PIX do CNPJ ou Email comercial'>
              <IconButton
                edge='end'
                onClick={e => handleClickLoadPIX(`pj_pix_key`)}
                onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
                aria-label='pj_pix_key-helper'
              >
                <Icon icon='mdi:auto-download' />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    )}
/>
```

I would like to use `setValue` here onBlur and onChange

**// ** JSX occupation **

```
<Controller
    name='contract_squad'
    control={occupationControl}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        id='contract_squad'
        onBlur={(e, newValue) => {
          toast.loading(JSON.stringify('onBlur: ' + e.target.value))

          setValue('contract_squad', e.target.value)
        }}
        onChange={(e, newValue) => {
          toast.loading(JSON.stringify('onChange: ' + newValue?.label))

          setValue('contract_squad', newValue?.label)
        }}
        filterOptions={(options, params) => {
          let filtered = filter(options, params)
          let { inputValue } = params
          let isExisting = options.some(option => inputValue === option.label)

          if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
            filtered.push({
              label: inputValue,
              value: inputValue
            })
          }

          return filtered
        }}
        handleHomeEndKeys
        options={contract_squadValues}
        getOptionLabel={option => {
          // Value selected with enter, right from the input
          if (typeof option === 'string') {
            return option
          }

          // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
          if (option.inputValue) {
            return option.inputValue
          }

          // Regular option
          return option.label
        }}
        renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.label}</li>}
        freeSolo
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            id='contract_squad'
            error={Boolean(occupationErrors.contract_squad)}
            label='Squad/Projeto'
            aria-describedby='contract_squad-helper'
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
 />
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags.